# how to login with pre-hashed password?

Tags: meteor

For added security, when a user tries to log in via my native iOS app (connected to meteor 1.5.1 via SSH DDP-connection) I want to hash the entered password before sending it to meteor.

**The problem:**

The Meteor.loginWithPassword method requires the password as a string in cleartext, so how do I login with a hashed password?

Comment: What does hashing a password do…? Then the hashed password becomes the password. What kind of attack does that prevent?

Comment: According to https://themeteorchef.com/blog/securing-meteor-applications it's good practise for the (non-meteor) client to hash the password, so the cleartext password isn't send over the wire.

Answer (score -2):

You can use the `Accounts._hashPassword()` function to hash the password first.

Use like this:

```
const hashed = Accounts._hashPassword('password123');
```